# routines:SSL23_GET_SERVER_HELLO:tlsv1 unrecognized name:s23 error on C++ program

Tags: c++, ssl, https

We are using a legacy C++ application/program to connect the external vendor site over the TLS protocol.
The vendor has recently changed its configuration setting for additional security. Since then this application starts throwing the above error. The TLS connection with the external vendor site looks good when we try through CURL, OpenSSL commands, and the python program. We are seeing the above issue only when we try to connect our C++ application. Can you help me resolve this issue? Please let me know if you need any further details.

```
bool connectSocket
(SocketId id, const char* hostname, unsigned int port, unsigned long waitMilliseconds)
```

{
assert( NULL != hostname );
assert(waitMilliseconds <= (unsigned long)UINT_MAX/USEC_PER_MSEC); //ADCR_changes

```
stringstream msg; 
    msg << "Connection Test Host: " <<hostname<<". & Port: " << port <<"\n";
    Logger::trace(Logger::cWarning,msg.str());

const struct sockaddr_in srv_addr = getAddress(hostname,port);



if(0!=::connect(id, (struct sockaddr*)&srv_addr, sizeof(srv_addr)))
{
    if(errno==EINPROGRESS)
    {
        if(!waitForWriteReady(id,waitMilliseconds*USEC_PER_MSEC))
            return false;
        int result=0;
        socklen_t result_size=sizeof(result);
        if(0!=getsockopt(id, SOL_SOCKET, SO_ERROR, &result, &result_size))
        {
            throwError(__LINE__,__FILE__,"ConnectionSocket::connect() could not determine socket status.");
        }
        if(result!=0)
        {
            errno=result;
            throwError(__LINE__,__FILE__,"ConnectionSocket::connect() could not connect to remote site(delayed).");
        }
    }
    else
    {
        throwError(__LINE__,__FILE__,"ConnectionSocket::connect() could not connect to remote site.");
    }
} else {

    stringstream msg1; 
    msg1 << "Connection is success Host: " <<hostname<<". & Port: " << port <<"\n";
    Logger::trace(Logger::cWarning,msg.str());
}
return true;
```

}

Comment: Your C++ program will be using a library (not part of Standard C++) to make the connection.  Without more information we can't help you.

Comment: Possible duplicate - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29808030/curl-error-35-error14077458ssl-routinesssl23-get-server-hellotlsv1-unreco

Comment: You likely connect with the wrong SNI extension to the server, i.e. it includes a hostname which is not configured for TLS at the server or it includes no SNI at all.

Comment: @SteffenUllrich, It may be but I am not sure what option in C++ program to set the correct SNI name? Can you please share more info on this?

Comment: @RichardCritten, It is using native C++ library only for connecting the Socket, not any third party library.

Comment: @SudhagarNagarajan: I have no idea what this "native" library should be. Please show the actual code.

Comment: I posted a snippet in this. Can you please take a look?